# List Views overlapping SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Recently, i had been using a LazyVStack to load views Lazy from dynamic data however as you may know, when the Views get complex, it can cause major performance issues and so ive started using a List however on the iOS 15 simulator, it seems to mess up and causes the views to overlap whereas on my normal device everything is just fine, any help as to what i could be doing wrong?

```
 Struct HomeView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            List {
                getTopView(geometry).anyView
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                    .listRowInsets(.init())
                    .padding(5)
                    
                ForEach(getDataViews) { view in
                    view.anyView
                        .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                        .listRowInsets(.init())
                    }
                    
                
                Color.clear
                    .id("bottom-2")
                    .frame(height: bottomInsetHeight() + 100)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
              
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .overlay(NavigationBar(title: "Home"))
                .overlay(ZStack {
                          ...
                }
                         
                         )
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the getTopView method I just have a vstack within a custom struct named DataView, which just contains an AnyView and id Property(I did this to try resolve the issue with lists as i thought it was an issue with Ids but same effect)

```
func getTopView(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> DataView {
        
        return DataView(anyView: AnyView(
        
            VStack {
            ...
            }
        )
        
    }
```

The actual data(posts), are loaded in a computed property returning an Array of DataView:

```
var getDataViews: [DataView] {
        var anyViews: [DataView] = []
            
            anyViews = viewModel.events.map { event in
                return DataView(anyView: AnyView(
                    ZStack {
                        EventCell(event: event)
                            .padding()
                            .padding(.bottom)
                        Navigator.navigate(route: .eventDetail(event)) {
                            Rectangle()
                        }
                        .opacity(0)
                    }
                    )
                )
            }
            return anyViews       
    }
```

The Data view struct:

```
struct DataView: Identifiable {
        var id: String = UUID().uuidString
        var anyView: AnyView
    }
```

If anyone is wondering what the geometry reader is for, it is being used in presenting a 'stories', i doubt it could be causing the issue
Yes I tried putting sections as well, same effect
[image: Simulator on iOS 15.2]

[image: Real Device iOS 14]

Comment: Did you try to add the  `.layoutPriority(1)` modifier to `getTopView(geometry).anyView` in `HomeView`?

Comment: @lazarevzubov I hadn't, but i just tried it and it didnt work, I wonder if it's a bug considering it works on my normal device

Comment: Storing a View inside a model struct looks problematic to me